# Clip Recycler View Edge Effect to Recycler View Background Drawable

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-drawable

I have a horizontally scrolling recycler view, where I am setting a background drawable on it which happens to have a rounded bottom left|bottom right corners.

When the user scrolls to the edge of the recycler, the recyclers edge effect appears, but it is not clipped to the background drawables bounds (makes sense, I certainly wouldn't expect it to do so by default).

Is there any way to clip this edge effect to the recyclers background drawable, such that this:

[image: edge effect]

Becomes:

[image: edge effect fixed]

Here is the layout containing the recycler view:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/itemRecycler"
        android:paddingStart="@dimen/section_spacing"
        android:paddingEnd="@dimen/section_spacing"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

The top two white boxes in the box diagrams above are *not* part of the recycler view. In addition, the background of the recycler view is not set in the XML, it is set dynamically.

This is because the recycler view can be the only|middle|top|bottom item in a dynamically created "section".

A "section" is the bit with the blue background.

I am provided with a JSON spec from a server with a list of "views" that should be rendered in a section.

Sections should have rounded corners.

Therefore, the position of the recycler view inside the section will dynamically determine it's background drawable. I.e:

- If it's the top most view and there are views after it in the same section, the recycler will only have rounded top corners.
- If it's the only view in the section, it will have rounded corners on all sides.
- If it's in the middle it will have no rounded corners.
- And finally, as in this example, if it's the bottom most view in the section, it will only have rounded bottom corners.

I set the background on the `FrameLayout` by the way.

Comment: can you please add your item layout? As you added in image, I think you need to add cardview with some corner radius.

Comment: Sure, I'll add some notes for context too.